# How to negate a property in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

I'd like to negate a boolean property as defined in pom.xml.

Meaning, given a property `${doSomething}` I need to pass `<skip>` to a plugin where the value of `<skip>` should be the negation of `${doSomething}`.

If `${doSomething}` is false, then I want to skip. If it is true, then I don't want to skip. Any ideas?

**Clarification**: I am not talking about using the negation of a property for profile activation. I just want to pass the negation of a boolean into a plugin.

Comment: could you share the current command you are using to skip involving doSomething.

Comment: @nullpointer It's a custom plugin. See `${download.cmake}` at https://github.com/cmake-maven-project/cmake-maven-project. I want to skip downloads if users set this property to false, but the plugin actually takes the negation of this value as input (`<skip>` parameter).

Comment: please add the details to the question, about the plugin context of your current pom.xml and the method of execution that you are following currently. I don't see `${download.cmake}` in the link provided.

Comment: Also if you are passing the value as `-Dskip=true` currently I don't see a point why you can't simply use `false` instead. Your current usage is not clear from the content in the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apart from profile activation, Maven doesn't have a boolean logic implemented. So if want to negate a property to pass it to a plugin, you'll need to do it yourself. It is a bit clumsy, but you could use the [`build-helper-maven-plugin:bsh-property`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/bsh-property-mojo.html) goal, which enables to write a [BeanShell script](http://www.beanshell.org/) and export variables defined in it as Maven properties:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.12</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>negate-prop</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>bsh-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <source>dontDoSomething = !${doSomething};</source>
        <properties>
          <property>dontDoSomething</property>
        </properties>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can't override the property, but you can define a new one containing the result of the negation; in the example above, it is `dontDoSomething`. This is ran in the `initialize` phase so that the rest of the plugins can use it as a parameter, with the standard `${dontDoSomething}`.

This could be enhanced to have a default value for `dontDoSomething` if `doSomething` doesn't exist.

```
<source>
  value = project.getProperties().getProperty("doSomething");
  dontDoSomething = value == null ? false : !Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
</source>
```

BeanShell is a scripting language that looks very much like Java and you can use existing Java methods. In the above, the property `"doSomething"` is retrieved from the project's properties (`project` is injected by the plugin at evaluation-time with the current Maven project); it it isn't defined, we return `false`, otherwise, we negate the value.

---

If `doSomething` is specifically a system property, it could also be possible to (ab)use the profile activation feature and have 2 profiles: one activated by a property being `true` and setting another to `false`, and a second profile doing the inverse:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>pro-1</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>doSomething</name>
        <value>!false</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <dontDoSomething>false</dontDoSomething>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>pro-2</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>doSomething</name>
        <value>false</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <properties>
      <dontDoSomething>true</dontDoSomething>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

This won't work if `doSomething` is a Maven property set in the `<properties>` tag for example. It will need to be passed as a system property with `mvn -DdoSomething=true|false`. The corresponding profile will be activated according to the value of the system property, which will define the `dontDoSomething` property to its inverse. If the property isn't defined, `pro-1` will be active, setting `dontDoSomething` to the default value of `false`. All of this is quite ugly though...

Comment: Can you please update the answer to contain a more complete example of using two profiles to set the boolean to true or false?

Comment: @Gili Yes, I just edited. Note that it'll only work if `doSomething` is a system property, not just any Maven property.

Comment: How do I make the BeanShell solution work for properties with default values? Meaning, if `${doSomething}` is defined, I want the negation; otherwise, I want a default value of `false`.

Comment: @Gili BeanShell is a scripting language which looks very much like Java. I edited further. I also edited the profile-based solution, as it is also doable with it.

Comment: Looks good, although [Boolean.valueOf(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-) will never return null, so your conditional can be simplified.

Comment: @Gili Oh yes, sorry for that! I must have done my tests wrong when I tried. The edit fixes that! `parseBoolean` or, as you point out `valueOf`, will return `false` on a `null` input, which would negate to `true`, so it still needs to be taken care of explicitly.

Comment: `System.getProperty("doSomething")` might also be useful for args passed on the command line (`-Darg=val`). This is a way for us to selectively disable plugins (utilising: `<skip>`), without the need to use profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer but I think you could try the following to invert the properties value (from http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). Declare another property where you invert the value of the first property:

```
<property>
    <name>dontDoSomething</name>
    <value>!${doSomething}</value>
</property>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because we're not talking about profile activation here. We are talking about defining a property that gets passed into a plugin.

Comment: It's not about WHAT but HOW. How do you invert a property's value.

Comment: Ah. Sorry about that :) I'll try that now.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you!

Comment: This config will activate the profile it is under if `dontDoSomething` is a system property with a value which is the opposite of the value of the system property `doSomething`. It won't define the Maven property `dontDoSomething` to some value dynamically.